# Buttons to behave as an Radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have many different buttons that fires different functions. In this example, I created total of 3 buttons, each firing a different function. The reason I want to stay away from using a radio buttons itself is because at some point in time, two buttons must be active.

For this example, what I want to do is, when a button is active: for example, Apple button is active and it fires a function, Banana and pear button should be not active and not fire its functions and vice versa (Also, active button should be shaded in a different color)

How can I accomplish this? Here is my code so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#AppleBTN').click(function() {
    apple();
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {}
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });

  $('#BananaBTN').click(function() {
    banana();
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {}
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });

  $('#PearBTN').click(function() {
    pear();
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {}
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});

function apple() {
  alert('apple');
}

function banana() {
  alert('banana');
}

function pear() {
  alert('pear');
}
```

```css
.btn {
  background: #3498db;
  border-radius: 0px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 30px;
  width: 70px;
}
.btn.active,
.btn:active {
  background: #124364;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn" id="AppleBTN">Apple</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="BananaBTN">Banana</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="PearBTN">Pear</button>
```

I feel that, for each different button function, I need to create a class of 'inactive'. Also, I've been trying to look up to see if there is a .toggleClass('inactive') or .inactive but failed to find the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of your `.btn` selector to target all three buttons, e.g. `$('.btn')`. Which is more maintainable than having to declare click event for each id.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn').click(function() {
    // remove active class except for the selected button
    $('.btn').not(this).removeClass('active'); 
    $(this).toggleClass('active');

    // get the id of the button element
    var id = $(this).attr("id"); 
    if (id == "AppleBTN")
        appleFunction();
    else if (id == "BananaBTN")
      bananaFunction();
    else if (id == "PearBTN")
      pearFunction();
  });
});
```

**Your different functions :**

```
function appleFunction() {
  alert("apple!");
}

function bananaFunction() {
  alert("banana!");
}

function pearFunction() {
  alert("pear!");
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cjaq1t4q/5/)

Answer (score 2):

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cjaq1t4q/6/)

**Description**
Basically this will iterate over all buttons in the `div` with class of `btns` it will then remove the class `active` from all buttons.  From here it will add the `active` css class to the button clicked.

**HTML**

```
<div class="btns">
  <button type="button" class="btn" id="AppleBTN">Apple</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn" id="BananaBTN">Banana</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn" id="PearBTN">Pear</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn').click(function() {
    $('.btns > button').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    // if you need to call a function you can pull any attribute of the button input
  });
});
```

Comment: You don't need to iterate over the matched set `$('.btns > button')` to remove the class. [`.removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) removes the specified class(es) or all classes from the set of matched elements. You can simply do `$('.btns > button').removeClass('active');` or even `$('.btn').removeClass('active');` using a simplified selector. Also, you're not using `that` so you might as well get rid of that line.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with few lines of code. Attach a *click* event handler using [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/). Inside the event, remove the class *active* from any button it may currently be on using [`.removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/). Then add the *active* class to the current selection using [`.addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/).

```js
$(function () {
    $('.btn').on('click', function () {
        $('.btn').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
.btn {
    background: #3498db;
    border-radius: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 30px;
    width: 70px;
}
.btn.active, .btn:active {
    background: #124364;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="AppleBTN">Apple</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="BananaBTN">Banana</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="PearBTN">Pear</button>
```

**Note:** I've simplified some of your CSS as well in the above example. When specifying a color where the three sets of hex digits are the same, you can specify one character for each of the three parts (i.e. `#ffffff` became `#fff`). In addition, when specifying a value of `0` there is no need to specify a unit so `border-radius: 0px` became `border-radius: 0`. Finally, when all of your padding values are the same such as `padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;` you can simplify this to `padding: 2px;`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally drop the jQ fanciness and class assignment and just go native.

HTML Sample:

```
<input type="radio" id="_set1_allclear" disabled hidden name="_set1" />

<input type="radio" disabled hidden name="_set1" />
<button type="button" onclick="if(document.getElementById('_set1_allclear').checked){ this.previousElementSibling.checked=true; callApple();}">Apple</button>
<input type="radio" disabled hidden name="_set1" />
<button type="button" onclick="if(document.getElementById('_set1_allclear').checked){ this.previousElementSibling.checked=true; callOrange();}">Orange</button>
```

From there, you can style the buttons via this CSS:

`button { /*default button style*/ }`
`#_set1_allclear ~ button { /*inactive button style*/ }`
`:checked + button { /*active button style*/ }`

All you have to do to full get this setup to work is add at the end of each of your `callFruit()` functions a `document.getElementById('_set1_allclear').checked=true;`

You could also throw that into the `onclick`s if you wanted to.

EDIT: Forgot to actually lock, rather than just providing the lock-trading mechanism. Woops.